# Curved membrane effect

Tags: physiology, hearing, bio-mechanics

> [Curved Membrane effect](http://www.neuros.org/index.php?option=com_topics&view=topic&id=31579&alias=curved-membrane-effect): Movements of the  tympanic membrane are more at the periphery than at the centre where malleus is attached which provides some leverage. This is called as curved membrane effect.

I am unable to comprehend how movement is more at periphery than at centre.
Practically movement is more at the centre as can be seen from  [this](http://147.162.36.50/cochlea/cochleapages/theory/extmid/middle_mov.gif)  .gif or from following image: [image]

So, why it is said that movement is more at periphery?

Comment: Why down vote??

Comment: "...as seen from the gif" Is the gif not accurate in showing the curved membrane effect?

Comment: Yes, see a better picture here http://doctorlib.info/physiology/medical/medical.files/image540.jpg